# AngularJS: Function to be called when the ng-model is non-empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input name field. I need to capitalize it if there is some text present in it. Here's how my current code looks like:

```
<input type="text" 
ng-model="basicClientInfo.firstName" 
data-ng-keydown="capitalization(basicClientInfo)"/>
```

I have already defined the capitalization function in my controller and it's working fine. The problem is with my event. capitalization function is triggered only if I hit a key.
How to trigger it when I use the program under automation (no mouse clicks and key-presses - just autofilling the forms)

My question is could the function be called if the field changes from empty to non-empty for the **first time**?

Comment: check `ng-change` is working for u :)

Comment: You should move capitalization logic from controller to directive. In directive template you could use ngChange on input element. Or you can move your logic to $parsers function of directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of Angular [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
```

OR

Make use of Angular [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

```
ng-change="capitalization(basicClientInfo)"
```

Worth a read: [Using ng-change instead of $watch in Angular](http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/11/using-ng-change-instead-of-$watch-in-angular/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value will be undefined at first and then won't be undefined again this will allow you to do something on the first assignment.

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(){
        return $scope.basicClientInfo.firstName;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(newValue && !oldValue){
        //     do something here
        }
    }
)
```

This is wasteful though and will fire every time the value changes and fail the conditional.